# How can I get Ninject 2 to use parameterless constructor for LINQ to SQL DataContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, ninject

I have started using Ninject 2 (downloaded from Github yesterday including the MVC extension project) with a project based on the following technologies:

- .Net 3.5 Sp1
- ASP.NET MVC 1.0
- LINQ to SQL

Nothing magical here - I have a few repository interfaces (named like IEntityRepository) that are implemented using LINQ to SQL in the runtime code (and using a hashtable in the unit test code). Each of these repositories need an instance of the DataContext from LINQ to SQL in order to talk to the database, so that is a constructor parameter on the concrete repository classes. The binding is set up like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<MyDataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

The reason for this is that I want to be able to share entities between different repositories if I should happen to need more of them, and with the LINQ to SQL datacontext unit of work philosophy, it seems to make sense to me to create one per HttpRequest.

I usually use the parameterless constructor for MyDataContext - I don't see that as a risk because this is used for an internal project on a test system, so the "built-in" connection string in the datacontext is harmless. However, since Ninject 2 is "greedy" and wants the constructor with the MOST parameters, and I can't really stick the `[Inject]` parameter into generated code in any meaningful way, I get an error whenever Ninject tries to create one of my controllers (which needs a repository, which needs the datacontext).

I have seen mention of `IConstructorScorer` and the ability to make an "inverted" one that would always use the constructor with the LEAST parameters, but then again, this would change how injection works for everything else - the default behavior is probably what I want for everything but the datacontext.

So - is there a nice, clean way to specify that this binding (and only this binding) should use a specific constructor? Can we do the same thing with providers as in Ninject 1, and perhaps supply our own "factory"? Or should I just give in and try to feed parameters into the datacontext that make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out - it is quite easily done by binding to a provider;

```
Kernel.Bind<MyDataContext>().ToProvider<ContextProvider>().InRequestScope();
```

Ninject will now call my ContextProvider whenever it needs to build one of those pesky DataContext objects. This is what my provider class looks like:

```
public class ContextProvider : IProvider
{
    #region IProvider Members

    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        return new MyDataContext();
    }

    public Type Type
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Seems like I got away with it - it works fine. :)

Answer (score 7):

I guess you could also use 'ToMethod' binding to avoid implementing custom provider, that's how I use that:

```
Kernel.Bind<MyDataConext>().ToMethod(c => new MyDataContext())
```

Comment: To be complete, I would add the `InRequestScope()` to ensure the lifetime of the DataContext is properly scoped.